# Error installing (arcore-preview.apk) via USB/debugging mode on an Android Smartphone

Tags: android, apk, adb, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I was following the instructions given on this https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started Google Developers Website but when I tried to install the APK file on my Android Device via Terminal (macOS)

Terminal gave me this error:

$ adb devices -l List of devices attached 93eafadd device usb:336592896X                     product:kenzo model:Redmi_Note_3 device:kenzo

$ adb install -r -d arcore-preview.apk Invalid APK file: arcore-preview.apk Sayans-iMac:~ sayan$

So I even transferred the APK to my Android device and tried to install it in the Android device it self manually, but I got this error: error parsing package!
I don't know why this is happening and I have also enabled USB debugging!

Comment: Are you using a supported device? https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have a an Android Device running marshmallow so this means I won't be able to develop an AR app?

Comment: Not with ARCore.

Comment: @MorrisonChang So what should I do now to get everything started for free I don't want to pay for Unity nor Unreal Engine so AS was the only option!

Comment: Unity and Unreal Engine both have a free tier. However if you really want to do AR you'll need appropriate hardware, no different than buying an Android phone to do mobile development.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have a 1.4 GHz iMac with intel. graphics and 8 GB RAM will that be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, but had not pointed adb to the right package:

```
adb install -r -d ~/Downloads/arcore-preview.apk
```

"Your download directory might vary."